# INFORMIX => Error: -9628 / Al momento de insertar en un tipo de dato List (Row) , en un store procedure

Tags: informix

Estimados buenos dias,

Obtengo el error:

> 9628 Type (type_name) not found.

Dejo la url, donde se puede leer a mas detalle el significado del error:

http://www.oninit.com/errorcode/index.php

En la siguiente linea de código, en el Servidor Secundario de **Informix**:

```
insert into  table(l_comp1)
  values ( ROW(l_pcmpcnpre, l_agen, l_pcmpccage, l_pcmpcfdes, l_pcppgfech, l_pcppgnpag, l_pcppgipag));
exception : looking for handler

SQL error = -9628 ISAM error = 0  error string =  = ""
exception : handler FOUND
expression:l_pcmpccage
evaluates to 40949849
expression:err_num
evaluates to -9628
```

Lo mas curioso es que en el Servidor Primario de Informix no hay ningun problema con ese insert pues se ejecuta correctamente.

La versión de Informix que tengo en el Servidor Secundario es:

**IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC9**

De antemano, Muchas Gracias por sus comentarios¡¡¡